# File download in angular js

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

How to download a file in a mobile device while giving the URL from the server, In Angularjs mobile application(Platform Cordova). The file can be of type pdf, image etc...

Comment: were you able to sanitize and produce a valid URL in your app?

Comment: Yes.I'm getting  the URL from Web API and I have checked it on the browser and its working

Comment: when you keep your finger pressed on the link (on a mobile)... what do you see? do you get the option (from the operating system) asking you to open it in another application?

Comment: No. Nothing Happens when I click on the link. Even if  '<a href >'  is used for redirection nothing happened in the device, but in the browser, it goes to the link page

Comment: add this to your page...  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

Comment: now the  file redirection for image only happens in the mobile device

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

This is Angular JS part:

```
import { Http, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';
...

constructor(
  private http: Http,
) { }

downloadFile() {
  return this.http
    .get('http://www.africau.edu/images/default', {
      responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob,
      search: // query string if have
    })
    .map(res => {
      return {
        filename: 'sample.pdf',
        data: res.blob()
      };
    })
    .subscribe(res => {
        console.log('start download:',res);
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(res.data);
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = res.filename;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        a.remove(); // remove the element
      }, error => {
        console.log('download error:', JSON.stringify(error));
      }, () => {
        console.log('Completed file download.')
      });
}
```

This is HTML part:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="downloadFile()"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Download</button>
```